# Java to map a range of float values to graphical display

Tags: java, floating-point-conversion

I want to take a range of float values **(subject)** that change and map them on to a static range of colours 0 - 255 for displaying on the screen.

The subject range of values start with the float being a minimum of 0.056582272 to the largest 0.34371486

when running calculation changes overtime to a minimum of 0.0791025 to the largest 4.5757337

If I map them using

number / 255 * largest

which in code is

```
thecol=elements[x][y][subject]*255/largest;
```

You see the colours at the beginning when I pop them on the screen, then at the end but nothing in between.

Comment: float values are too low and the rounding to byte or int will nullify them. I´d suggest first doing the calcs on a bigger integer  such as MAX_INT and then scale it down to the 0-255 range with integer calculations

Answer (score 0):

You did not factor in the minimum of the range for your calculation.

```
float rangeSize = largest - smallest;
float mappedTo0to1 = (value - smallest) / rangeSize; // Map to range 0 - 1.
int mappedResult = (int) (mappedTo0to1 * 255); // Map to range you want. (0 - 255).
```

The trick with verifying these kind of functions is to look at the lowest and highest input values possible.